# When pressing tab, how can I make fish complete to directory/ instead of directory/prefix?

Tags: autocomplete, fish

I'm using fish shell. Let's say that I have a directory named `books`, containing files `title-1`, `title-2` and `title-3`:

```
$ tree books
books/
├── title-1
├── title-2
└── title-3

0 directories, 3 files
```

If I type `git add boo` and press <kbd>tab</kbd>, fish will automatically complete to `git add books/title-` . I can press <kbd>tab</kbd> multiple times to cycle through the files `books/title-1`, `books/title-2` and `books/title-3`.

I would prefer it if fish completed to `git add books/` instead, the way bash or zsh does it. I'm used to that way, and it's more convenient to run `git add` against a directory rather than a list of files. How can I configure fish to complete this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.

Fish's git completions print the entire path and there is no configuration option to disable this.

You can press ctrl-w to delete back to the last "/".